# How run function in react style if statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to run function in react style if statement but getting error:

> Line 89:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression  no-unused-expressions

where i mistake?

here is my code:

```
anim() {
   console.log('function running')
}

render() {
    function onChange(isVisible) {
      isVisible ? (
       this.anim()
      ) : null
    }
......
```

Comment: remove  "()" after the "?"

Comment: are you defining a function inside the render method? may I ask why? is not really clear where the error is.

I would extract the onChange out of the render method and refactor it there

Comment: what do you want to return from that function?

Comment: This is your linter telling you that there is a value returned from an expression being discarded without explicit specification

Comment: So here i can't call function ?

Comment: not but you can make that animation and use conditional rendering to display your animation.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to declare a function instead render method instead declare it outside

and your render function should be something like this

```
render() {
    const {isVisible} = this.state;
    return(
           <div> 
             {isVisible ? "I'll be printed if visible" : "I'll be printed if false"} 
          </div>
    )}
```

Ideally, you should be updating the state of isVisbile inside the onChange function, and when the state values are changed the render function will be called and thus your ternary operator which is the IF statement will be executed again and rendered accordingly.

using ternary operator you can check the condition which you want

Comment: Not sure if this is related

Comment: Yes I think this is related because you cannot declare the function inside render method and the above example shows the right way of using IF statement in react while rendering

Comment: It's not what i'm asking about

Comment: i just wan't to run some js animation in my function. It's not important there is not working console log also. here is i put outside of the render my function.  but getting same error. I think this is related some syntax error getSome(isVisible) {
    {isVisible ? (
      tl.to(this.cover, 0.5, {
        scaleX: 0,
        ease: Expo.easeInOut,
        force3d: true,
        rotationZ: 0.01
      })
    ) : null}
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
  render() {
        function onChange(isVisible) {
          isVisible ?  this.anim() : null;
        }
```